# How to create and use WebBrowser in background thread?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, browser

How can I create System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser in background STA thread? I try use some code like this:

```
var tr = new Thread(wbThread);
tr.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
tr.Start();

private void wbThread()
{
     CWebBrowser browser = new CWebBrowser();
     var text = browser.Navigate("http://site.com", CWebBrowser.EventType.loadCompleted).Body.InnerHtml;
}
```

CWebBrowser - custom class, wich delegate System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser object Navigate method and wait until page completed loads. The problem is LoadCompleted event on System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser object never raises. I found some solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271581/432853), but it does not work (can't find method Application.Run() on my WPF app).

```
public class CWebBrowser : ContentControl
{
    public readonly System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser innerWebBrowser;
    private readonly AutoResetEvent loadCompletedEvent;
    private readonly AutoResetEvent navigatedEvent;

    public enum EventType
    {
        navigated, loadCompleted
    }

    public CWebBrowser()
    {
        innerWebBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        loadCompletedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        navigatedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
        host.Child = innerWebBrowser;
        Content = host;

        innerWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted +=new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(innerWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
        innerWebBrowser.Navigated += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(innerWebBrowser_Navigated);
    }

    void innerWebBrowser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        navigatedEvent.Set();
    }

    void innerWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((sender as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).ReadyState != System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) || innerWebBrowser.IsBusy)
            return;

        var doc = innerWebBrowser.Document;
        loadCompletedEvent.Set();
    }

    public System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument Navigate(string url, EventType etype)
    {
        if (etype == EventType.loadCompleted)
            loadCompletedEvent.Reset();
        else if (etype == EventType.navigated)
            navigatedEvent.Reset();

        innerWebBrowser.Navigate(url);

        if (etype == EventType.loadCompleted)
            loadCompletedEvent.WaitOne();
        else if (etype == EventType.navigated)
            navigatedEvent.WaitOne();

        System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc = null;
        Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(
            delegate
            {
                doc = innerWebBrowser.Document;
            }));

        return doc;
    }
}
```

Thansk for all advices and sorry for my bad english :o(

Comment: You are breaking the STA contract, the thread must pump a message loop.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread/4271581#4271581

Comment: Why are you using the com based Form?   The WPF control is System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?  Are you doing all this just to try and the html output from a web site?

Comment: I use winforms WebBrowser, because I want use ReadyState property. And I use webbrowser for downloading pages, executing a lot of javascripts.

Comment: Hans Passant, could you comment your post? (post a sample) Thanks

Comment: So the purpose of the code is to get the rendered html after all the scripts have processed?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the default WebBrowser control like this?

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(startNavigate);
}

void startNavigate()
{
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.LoadCompleted += new LoadCompletedEventHandler(wb_LoadCompleted);
    wb.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(wb_Navigated);
    wb.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
}

void wb_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Content
}

void wb_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Content when the document finished loading.
}
```

Edit: You are using old `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control, instead `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` which is part of WPF.

Comment: Try run your code yourself - it doesn't work :( (event never fire)

Comment: I edited my post to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. And yes, the navigate event is fired. I just tried it.

Comment: But is it true, that in your edited solution WebBrowser control created in main dispatcher thread? Big pages with a lot of javascript will be render at this thread and application will freezed?

Comment: `BeginInvoke` runs asynchronously, so it's very safe - will not freeze your application.

Comment: But I'm also need wait for complete loading and rendering page after it has been navigated. If I will use BeginInvoke() it was freeze my app. Can you run your solution with my CWebBrowser object? App starts freeze at WaitOne() method :(.

Comment: See my edit. I added `LoadCompelted` event. Also, you are using old `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`, instead `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` which is WPF control.

Comment: I use old webbrowser, because I want use ReadyState property. But in your last solution LoadCompleted event never raised too. Do you try it yourselft? (sorry for my question :().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6161/discussion-between-dmitriy-and-tomislav-markovski)

Comment: hi. im trying this as well, `loadcompleted` is never fired. any solutions fellows?

Comment: Bringing this thread back to life, I have followed instructions here and found that sometimes my loadcompleted event does not fire. This seems to happen when the browser is not a child of something. When I make it a child of the Grid it locks my application up. If I try to make it a child of a grid in the LoadCompleted event it doesn't get added as the event does not fire. The LoadCompleted event also does not fire when the control is added to the Grid in the Navigated event. Does anyone have any other ideas?